# Computing complex derivative of $zRe(z)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$f(x,y) = x^2 - ixy$. Where is this complex differentiable?

$\lim_{\triangle x \to 0} \frac{x^2 + \triangle x + i(x+ \triangle x)y - x^2 - ixy}{\triangle x} = 1+iy$

$\lim_{i\triangle y \to 0} \frac{x^2 +\triangle y + ix(y + \triangle y) - x^2 - ixy}{\triangle y} = i-x$

But apparently $f$ is only differentiable at $z=0$. I don't understand why that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $h\neq 0$ and $z$ be any complex number, then: $$((z+h)\mathrm{Re}(z+h)-z\mathrm{Re}(z))/h=\mathrm{Re}(z)+\mathrm{Re}(h)-z\mathrm{Re}(h)/h$$
You have to prove that this limit exists iff $z=0$.